# How to get effective permissions for a user on AD LDS entry in C#?

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory, ldap

I have 3rd party application using AD LDS to store its hierarchical data and I need to provide web UI in ASP.NET MVC for this system. It is using DACLs on directory entries to control users' access permissions for individual entries.

I have found few good articles explaining how to read `ActiveDirectoryAccessRules` for `DirectoryEntry` but I cannot find any good way to **calculate effective permissions for specific user**. Is there any supporting Microsoft API or library available or I need to invent my own way?

*Reference URLs for people investigating on similar subjects:*

[Writing your own AD/ADAM permissions editor - 3](http://blogs.interakting.co.uk/post/Writing-your-own-ADADAM-permissions-editor-Part-3.aspx)

[The .NET developer's guide to directory services programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=kGApqjobEfsC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=SecurityMasks.Dacl&source=bl&ots=p4uvYbSQN5&sig=NP_xILVTFv7GaZ_E7AFF5WL1qS4&hl=en&ei=K-LOTKKKI4acOrypgbsB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Access control lists in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ADPermissions.aspx)

Comment: The cheapest way to check what attributes the current user can modify on an object is to check its "allowedAttributesEffective" attribute.  This is an attribute calculated by AD on the fly.  It takes care all the inherited permissions and deny permissions override.  Similary, you can use "allowedAttributes" to check what attributes the current user can read.  Of course, if the current user doesn't have permission on the whole object, the attempt to read "allowedAttributes" or "allowedAttributesEffective" will fail

Comment: @Harvey: but that way i will need to impersonate user i'm checking effective permissions for, right? Thanks for the tip, i will definitely check this out.

Comment: @Ignor Yes, you need to impersonate user to check the effective permissions.  You can also take a look at AccessCheck and GetEffectiveAces.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374815(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637(v=vs.85).aspx.  But warn you.  We hit some problems when using these two API.  BTW, a correction on my previous comment.  "allowedAttribues" doesn't return the read permission.  So, don't use it.  "AllowedAttributeEffective" DOES return the write permission.

Comment: @IgorRomanov did you found any solution to you problem?

Comment: @HarveyKwok Where we can find "allowedAttributesEffective" and  "allowedAttributes" attribute property for object.

Comment: @Ignor If you are using ADSI edit, you can see it only if you turn on to check the constructed attribute at the Filter button

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:
http://www.conarc.com/blog/2010/03/25/programmatically-getting-effective-directoryfile-permissions/

Comment: The link is dead.