# How to validate access to Active Directory?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am working on some sort of health monitoring and I want to validate that my application has access and proper right in Active Directory. When I initialise `DirectoryEntry`, this will show me that I see given domain/path from the machine. That's OK, but I need to check if I am able to read/write in the domain. It that even possible without creating actual object in AD?

Thanks in regards

Comment: Take a look at comments in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071260/how-to-get-effective-permissions-for-a-user-on-ad-lds-entry-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, it was quite easy with oldovets' comment. Here is the code I used:

```
                using (DirectoryEntry entry = directorySearcher.FindOne()?.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    if (entry == null)
                    {
                        //report error
                    }

                    entry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "allowedAttributesEffective" });
                    if (entry.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (this.properties == null || this.properties.All(property => entry.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Contains(property)))
                        {
                            //sufficient rights
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //insufficient rights
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //not possible to check attribute "allowedAttributesEffective", it is missing or you have insufficient rights to read it
                    }
                }
```